# amp-lightbox: How to close current modal and open other in one action?

Tags: amp-html

I use amp-lightbox component to show detail information: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox/.

amp-lightbox tag has `on` attribute to open and close modal window:

- for open: on="tap:my-lightbox"
- for close: on="tap:my-lightbox.close"

I need to show "Next item", so I need close and open at a moment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple actions at the same time by separating with a comma:

```
on="tap:my-lightbox1.close,my-lightbox2.open"
```

[EDIT] More about AMP events and actions here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-actions-and-events.md

Comment: Works. Can you show me a link to the documentation about actions, please?

Comment: Yes, of course, I should have included in the answer the first time! Answer updated